# Spawned objects values (sounds/scores) being mixed on Android but are correct in Unity2D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, audio

I'm making a simple game to learn Unity2D and C# where you have to catch balls falling from the sky. Each ball plays a different sound when caught in the basket and affects the score in different ways.

There are 3 types of balls:

- Normal ball - Plays a "Boink!" sound when caught and adds 1 to players score.
- Dirty ball - Plays a "Booo!" sound when caught and subtracts 2 from players score.
- Special ball, plays a "Ding!" sound when caught and adds 5 to players score.

These all work fine when pressing play in Unity2D. The sounds are playing on the correct ball type and the scores are being updated as expected.

When building and running on an Android device however, the following happens:

- Normal ball - Plays a "Booo!" sound when caught and subtracts 2 from players score.
- Dirty ball - Plays a "Boink!" sound when caught and adds 1 to players score.
- Special ball, plays no sound when caught and adds 0 to players score.

Below is a example of my code.

#### Creating balls:

```cs
IEnumerator Spawn()
{
    Instantiate(GetBall(), spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
}

GameObject GetBall()
{
    float randomBallChance = Random.Range(1, 101);
    if (randomBallChance <= 60)
    {
        return normalBall;
    }
    else
    {
        return (if (randomBallChance <= 70) ? specialBall : dirtyBall);
    }
}
```

#### Update score and play sounds:

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    switch (collision.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case "normalBall": 
        {
            score += scoreValue;
            normalSound.Play();
            break;
        }
        case "dirtyBall":
        {
            score -= (scoreValue * 2);
            dirtySound.Play();
            break;
        }
        case "specialBall ":
        {
            score += 5;
            specialSound.Play();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Can't for the life of me work out why everything is fine when playing on Unity  but not on Android.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of changing everything I could possibly think of, the answer was uninstalling the app.

The previous install of the app only had 1 ball instead of 3. For some reason it seems to have bugged out on upgrading after adding the 2 new balls and using File > Build And Run instead of removing it and re-installing the new version.

Steps:

- Uninstall the app from the device
- File > Build And Run